# It's not you but me who can solve this riddle!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I am half of who I am,
> yet I am twice of who I am.
> Show me, the answer of this riddle,
> and I will give you a little giggle.

What am I?

The answer will explain all 4 lines!

> Hint 1: I've added a comma to the 3rd sentence
>
> Hint 2: Someone got 'half' of the answer here already!

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the punctuation in the 3rd line has useful meaning?

Comment: All I will say is, it gets you closer to the answer =)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's

> meme

I am half of who I am,

> "me" is half of "meme" ("I" as a definition, "me", is half of ["who I am" = the answer])

yet I am twice of who I am.

> "meme" is twice "me" (["I" = the answer] is twice "who I am" as a definition, "me")

Show me, the answer of this riddle,
and I will give you a little giggle.

> The answer is "meme" which is usually supposed to be funny and make people laugh.

Comment: I've given up hope on which answer OP is fishing for.  I just hope he selects one as correct so we can move on, and he reconsiders how to handle future puzzles with answers that aren't as unique as he thought they were.

Comment: Very answer. Many clever. So like.

Comment: @Will you're fired

Comment: @question_asker maybe Will meant "Very clever answer. Like so many"

Comment: @manshu I like you, manshu

Comment: I feel as giddy as Maru jumping into a box and jumping out of a box and jumping into a box...

Comment: There we go, a winner!

Answer (score 8):

The answer is

> the number zero.

I am half of who I am:

> $\frac{0}{2}=0$.

yet I am twice of who I am:

> $0 \times 2=0$.

Show me the answer of this riddle,
and I will give you a little giggle:

> This one is on you, OP.  You better make [a joke about the number zero](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=jokes%20about%20the%20number%20zero) or you'll unfairly invalidate this answer.

Comment: Nice catch on using zero!  However a joke isn't necessary for the answer, it's something else!

Answer (score 6):

It is:

> Butt?

I am half of who I am,

> A butt can be made of two butt cheeks

yet I am twice of who I am.

> Same as above

Show me the answer of this riddle,

> Butts are usually hidden behind clothing so you can't really see it

and I will give you a little giggle.

> Seeing or saying "Butt" can cause lots of people to laugh

Comment: it's not the correct answer but it does gives me a giggle =P

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is

> Semi-colon (sign is ;)

I am half of who I am,

> Half of 'fullstop'

yet I am twice of who I am.

> Twice of comma,

Show me, the answer of this riddle,
and I will give you a little giggle.

> It is used in the wink emoticon as ;)

Comment: If this isn't the right answer I will be *extremely* surprised

Comment: Isn't semicolon more like "half-colon" by definition?

Comment: good try but this is not the answer

Comment: @question_asker you should be *extremely* surprised by now..:D ;)

Comment: @orion i learned in my school that semicolon halts the sentence more than comma but less than a full-stop. But I am not sure why is it called semi-colon, you may find something useful [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111789/why-is-called-semicolon-and-what-is-its-history)

Answer (score 4):

Is it:

> Infinity?

I am half of who I am,

> Infinity divided by two is still infinity and infinity can be cut into two equal pieces.

yet I am twice of who I am.

> Infinity times two is still infinity

Show me the answer of this riddle,

> Infinity is kinda hard to comprehend. It is more of a concept rather than a number but everyone probably disagrees with that.

and I will give you a little giggle.

> To write infinity in its opother form, you have to draw a sideways 8, or sometimes a BUTT!

Comment: Not the right answer but upvote for imaginations! 8)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> the word "me"

I am half of who I am:

> "I am" has 4 characters (including whitespace). "me" is 2.

yet I am twice of who I am:

> Twice of "I"(1character). "me"(2characters). "I" and "me" have synonymous meanings.

Show me, the answer of this riddle,

> You're saying "me" is "the answer of this riddle"

and I will give you a little giggle:

> The answer is so obvious it's in the title and in the third line, it could be considered a little funny it took so long to figure it out.

Comment: Not the right answer but very close!

Comment: @Alex, is it *I*, which is still an *I* when its length/width is halved and doubled?

Comment: @user1717828 nope, but this answer is the closest so far

Comment: Nice puzzle but I find this answer even better and original than the actually correct answer =P

Answer (score 1):

> Brain

I am half of who I am,
yet I am twice of who I am.

> As per the title hint, brain is the thing that solves the riddle. Brain has two hemispheres, so it's two halves.

Show me, the answer of this riddle,
and I will give you a little giggle.

> The brain is the thing that will see the irony in the answer and it controls your actions, so you will giggle.

Comment: Not the answer but good attempt!